# Replace JSON Values in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My question is the following.
I have a JSON Object in Angular and I want to replace all ";" with "" from a specific key.

```
$scope.users = data;
```

In this case I want to run a loop  and replace the values only in

```
$scope.users[i]['pic'];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide your JSON code?

Comment: {"uid":"295","username":"xxx","password":"1234","email":"xx@xx.com","usertype":"3","profilePic":"pics\/profileIcon.png;"}

Comment: So you would like `"pics\/profileIcon.png;"` to be changed to `"pics\/profileIcon.png"`?

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: exactly!For all the strings in my JSON Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.users=[{'pic':'df;gd;'},{'pic':'adfgadfgadfgad;adf   fdag;'},{'pic':'adfdff; ;;;'}];


angular.forEach($scope.users,function(value, key) {
value.pic= value.pic.replace(/;/g ,'');
},{});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fp5roLae/

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.users = [{"uid":"295","pic":"picsprofileIcon.png;"},{"uid":"295","pic":"picsprofileIcon.png;"}]

for(i in $scope.users){ 
    $scope.users[i]['pic'] = $scope.users[i]['pic'].replace(";", "");    
}
```